# Using a number of equations from a paper, how to mention it in my paper

Tags: journals, writing

I am using a number of equations from a different paper. I am using those to derive another quantity.

Is it appropriate to just mention them one after another, without stating the assumptions behind the equations etc, since I am already citing the previous paper like

Equation 1 -- (1)

Equation 2 -- (2)

Equation 3 -- (3)

.

.

.

.

.

Equation 14 -- (14)

then state the physical meaning of each parameter in the above equations?

I tried looking at some example papers but couldn't find any in the particular journal I am writing for.

If it were 1 equation, it would be fine, but I am not sure how to handle so many equations.

Or should I just reference the main equation and state the rest in the supplemental section? I just read and it seems putting too many equations in a paper is not a good idea.

Comment: It depends on what you're writing. I normally write a brief paragraph beneath each equation which describes what the equation represents and the obvious things about it such as the parameter meanings and the reasoning for certain aspects of the equation. If I'm repeating myself in the paper I'll just refer inline to equation (1), and if I have to add MANY equations, I'll usually try to put "where the parameters \alpha, \beta, and \stuff" have their usual meanings. Unless I'm showing a set of three equations that you get at the same time from one derivation, I normally have at least some text.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique That's a good approach, and the one you'd typically see in papers. However, if alpha_989 really has 14 equations, and especially if they are not self-explanatory enough, putting them in an appendix sounds more sensible to me.

Comment: Oh yeah, 14 equations is appendix-material for sure. Somehow I missed the '14' part ;)

Comment: You want your paper to be clear and readable.  Do what makes it so.

Comment: Thank you @101010111100  for your comments. I think its probably more appropriate to move it to the appendix, and cite the main equation. It was a lot of work to find the relevant equations, and connecting the dots, so I kindof thought that maybe if I put all the equations in the main body, it would kindof show the amount of work that went into finding the equations. 

But I guess a paper is judged not on the basis of the amount of work but on the importance of the results. Sometimes thats a hard pill to swallow.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique, yeah.. thats what I usually do when I have a few equations. I will write out the equations, explain the physical meaning of the parameters, and where it is coming from in a simplified fashion. But with the 14 or so equations I cited, it would take another paper to just describe what the meaning is. So maybe its best left to the appendix.

Its not completely cut and dry in the sense, i am using some equations directly, and then have to use some equations from another paper to make the connection between those equations and the previous equations I have derived in the paper.

Comment: So I will probably mention the main equation from paper 1, and the connecting equation from paper 2, and the equations I derived in my own paper. and leave the rest of the equations from paper 1 in the appendix.

Comment: @Kimball, Thanks.. You are right.. while I have written previous papers, those were trimmed and edited by my professors, and I didnt have to think about whether the paper was clear and readable etc.

For this paper, my advisor basically gave me free reign, and basically told me that I should write and submit the paper by myself as a corresponding authoer. So I am kindof trying to figure out the balance between explaining everything in a self-contained paper vs making it readable.

Comment: Yes, there's always a balance to be struck, and it's not easy, but this is part of the challenge in writing papers, and one can get better with practice.  A couple suggestions are: try something and draft it up, then (1) have other people look at it an give feed back, and (2) put it away for a week or so, then read it again.  I often realize that explanations that seemed clear to me at the time weren't anymore after I stopped thinking about it for awhile.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the common practice in your field, but, as a mathematician, I feel that you have approached this thing from the wrong direction. You don't reuse *equations* from another paper; you reuse *theorems*. A theorem is a statement like

> If A and B and C are true, then equations D and E hold, where the symbol F is defined as... and G is defined as...

Maybe the authors of the other paper did not formulate their result as a theorem, but it is one. It is a sloppy but common habit to throw the derivation of a result in front of the reader directly, instead of first stating it then proving it.

Another important point to note is that there are hypotheses and assumptions under which these equations hold; if you focus on equations rather than on the whole 'theorem' package, this information can very easily get lost.

So, my suggestion is: reformulate those results as theorems. It could be a single theorem with 14 separate equations as the thesis, if they are all related.

If the word *theorem* sounds too pompous, use *proposition*. If your result seems too simple to deserve this name, use *lemma*.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the main equation from the previous work and for the others refer the reader to the main paper.

About explaining the equation, if you give an introduction before formulating the problem, the reader would be prepared for your idea.

Moreover, you should illustrate the coherence of the equations clearly to get interests from the readers (and especially your reviewers). The recommendation is to use the graphs and plots (visual description) to notice the reader about your idea, proofs, and results.